# How to run PHPUnit test inside a running container

Tags: docker, unit-testing, docker-compose, phpunit, phpstorm

I use PhpStorm in development. To run a test I do below 3 commands:

```
docker-compose exec app bash
cd app/
vendor/bin/phpunit unitTest/Sample.php
```

I want to be able to run the test just by clicking the "Run" button inside PhpStorm.

I tried to accomplish it using docs from IntelliJ but they overwhelmed me.
I thought I just need to change the interpreter path but couldn't understand how to attach to a running docker.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you need to add your Docker-compose based interpreter. See [this](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/configuring-remote-interpreters.html) guide.
[image: php interpreter]
Second, add a PHPUnit configuration based on this interpreter, see ["Integrate PHPUnit with a PhpStorm project﻿"](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/using-phpunit-framework.html#php_test_frameworks_phpunit_integrate).
[image: phpunit config]
After that you should be able to simply Run the tests using IDE UI.

Comment: I will just add that, you don't have to use `/opt/project` but the path you see on top on the second image inside `Path mappings`. And the first image, you should click `Connect to existing container ('docker-compose exec')` instead of `docker-compose run`

Comment: I was able to run the tests.
However it run the tests from different directory what gives me errors.
How can implement the "cd app/" into the configuration?

Comment: Update: I was able to fix it by adding 
    `working_dir: /app` to docker-compose