# PhpStorm: Cannot parse PHPUnit version output: Could not open file: /var/www/docroot/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/phpunit

Tags: docker, docker-compose, phpstorm

I'm trying to setup PHPUnit in PhpStorm, so I can run tests from inside my IDE.

I have Docker setup in PhpStorm, and I can see my containers in the 'Services'-tab and `exec` stuff in them, from inside PhpStorm.

And if I click <kbd>Update</kbd> button (the circular arrows) next to 'Path to script', then it throws the error:

```
Cannot parse PHPUnit version output: Could not open file: /var/www/docroot/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/phpunit
```

It can be seen here:

[image: Docker test struggles - Cannot parse PHPUnit version]

### The overarching question

What is failing here? I'm guessing that PhpStorm is trying to access PHPUnit inside the Docker-container, but can't find that `phpunit`-file (from the error).

... Oh, yeah - and how do I fix it? :-)

---

### Quick solution attempts and thoughts

1. If I run this in my terminal: `docker-compose exec php bin/phpunit --log-junit testresults.xml`, then all the tests run. Great!
2. If I, inside PhpStorm, right click the `php`-container and choose `exec` and paste in: `php bin/phpunit --log-junit testresults.xml`, then the tests all run in PhpStorm. Great!
3. I could also try and find the `phpunit.phar`-file directly and point to that. But if I access the container (with `docker-compose exec -i php /bin/bash`) and then search for the file (with `find . -name 'phpunit.phar'`) then nothing is found.
4. Default configuration file is blank. I also tried setting that to: `/Users/myusername/Code/myproject/phpunit.xml.dist`. Same result.
5. What if PHPUnit is installed in the php-image - and therefore not via Composer or something? Hmm... The only `phpunit`-line in the composer-file seem to be this: `"symfony/phpunit-bridge": "^5.2",` ...

### Solution attempt 1: Check for the file

If I check for the file it's looking for in the vendor directory, then I can't seem to find the file it's looking for:

```
| vendor
  | ...
  | phpunit
    | php-timer
      | .github
      | src
      | tests
      | ... 
  | ...
  | ...
```

It looks like something is missing. But the tests can run inside the docker-container?! Hmm.!

And it's the same inside the container:

[image: Docker test struggles - Cannot parse PHPUnit version]

### Links and resources

- [Docker container with PHPUnit: Could not open input file: /var/www/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/phpunit](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360006768379-Docker-container-with-PHPUnit-Could-not-open-input-file-var-www-vendor-phpunit-phpunit-phpunit)
- [PHPUnit "use Composer autoloader" could not parse PHPUnit version output.](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/115000455850-PHPUnit-use-Composer-autoloader-could-not-parse-PHPUnit-version-output-)
- I tried following this (old) guide here, for the setup. He blasts through it, without my error: [Running PHPUnit Tests in PhpStorm with Docker](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I7aGWO6K3Ho).
- [How to run PHPUnit test inside a running container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73481723/how-to-run-phpunit-test-inside-a-running-container)

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out!

It was because `phpunit` was located in a weird location inside my project. See here:

[image: Solution to PHPUnit-location]