# Unable to run single PHP-test in PhpStorm (inside Docker-container). Error: Cannot open file "/path/to/my/project/tests/SomeTestClass.php"

Tags: docker, docker-compose, phpunit, phpstorm

**Running all tests (works)**

When I run *all tests* inside PhpStorm, then I go to "Run" >> "MyProject PhpUnit Test". This outputs and runs a command like this:

> `[docker-compose://[/path/to/my/project/docker-compose.yml]:php/]:/usr/local/bin/php /var/www/docroot/bin/phpunit --configuration /var/www/docroot/phpunit.xml.dist --teamcity`

That runs all tests inside PhpStorm, so far so good!

---

**Running single test (does not work)**

If I go to a single test, right-click on the test-name and click:
"Run testAppendShortToAnswers..."
Shortcut: <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>R</kbd>
then it outputs and runs a command like this:

> `[docker-compose://[/path/to/my/project/docker-compose.yml]:php/]:/usr/local/bin/php /var/www/docroot/bin/phpunit --configuration /var/www/docroot/phpunit.xml.dist --filter "/(App\\Tests\\Entity\\CardTest::testAppendShortToAnswers)( .*)?$/" --test-suffix CardTest.php /path/to/my/project/tests/Entity --teamcity`

And throws an error immediately:

```txt
Cannot open file "/path/to/my/project/tests/Entity.php".

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I'm assuming that it's because it tries to access that file, not from inside my Docker-container, but rather from my host-machine.

How do I fix this, so I can run a single test in PhpStorm?

---

### Info about the setup

I struggled a bit setting up PhpStorm to run the tests, but you can see [the big problem I had (and the solution) alongside links and whatnot here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74052414).

I'm on a Mac. It's a Symfony-project, where PhpUnit is located in a folder in the project-root (`/bin/phpunit`). So it's not installed via Composer.
I'm not really sure why it's setup this way.

---

### Solution attempt 1: Running single test from the terminal

If I go to the terminal and run this command:

```
docker-compose exec php /usr/local/bin/php /var/www/docroot/bin/phpunit --filter testAppendShortToAnswers
```

The it runs as it should. Hmm... But I ideally I would like to run it straight from PhpStorm, so I can utilize the <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>R</kbd>-shortcut.

Comment: This one seems similar to your (overall at least). OP could not reproduce it later. Also provided some workarounds/attempts. Have a look -- https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-67399/Impossible-to-run-a-single-unit-test-in-the-correct-path-in-a-docker-container-defined-via-docker-compose

Answer (score 1):

@LazyOne pointed me in the right direction.

It was because I had a path mapping setup incorrectly.

So by changing that, then it works now:

[image: incorrect path mapping]

---

**I had it like this:**

```txt
/Users/MYUSERNAME/Code/MYPROJECTNAME/some-wrong-project   ->  /var/www/docroot
```

**And it fixed it to change it to:**

```txt
/Users/MYUSERNAME/Code/MYPROJECTNAME/the-project-I-am-working-on  ->  /var/www/docroot
```